# horas en números decimales python

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, datetime

Tengo una Data Frame con distintas horas de registro en formato militar (22:15 en vez de 10:15 pm); intento convertir las 24 horas en una equivalencia a 1.0 para que las 22:15 equivalgan a 22.25/24 = 0.927083 o 92.7% del día
**nota**: el 0.25 proviene de la transformación 15 minutos en el 25% de una hora

Intente de esta manera:

```
data['Hora']= float(data['Hora'].str[:2])/24 + float(data['Hora'].str[3:5])/600
```

pero por algún motivo no se puede convertir la serie de string a float ni a int

```
TypeError: cannot convert the series to
```

La data va mas o menos así:

```
Hora     X1     X2      X3
22:00 1.10788 1.10803 1.10772 
22:15 1.10777 1.10785 1.1075 
22:30 1.1078 1.10788 1.10774 
22:45 1.10781 1.10785 1.10742 
23:00 1.10753 1.10769 1.10739 
23:15 1.10756 1.10765 1.10742 
23:30 1.1075 1.1076 1.10745 
23:45 1.10756 1.10772 1.10741 
00:00 1.10765 1.10794 1.10764 
00:15 1.10778 1.10808 1.10778 
00:30 1.10787 1.10834 1.10779
```

y la necesito asi:

```
  Hora           X1      X2      X3     X4
 0.9167     1.10788 1.10803 1.10772 1.10775
 0.9271     1.10777 1.10785 1.1075  1.10781
 0.9375     1.1078  1.10788 1.10774 1.1078
 0.9479     1.10781 1.10785 1.10742 1.10752
 0.9583     1.10753 1.10769 1.10739 1.10755
 0.9688     1.10756 1.10765 1.10742 1.10749
 0.9792     1.1075  1.1076  1.10745 1.10757
 0.9896     1.10756 1.10772 1.10741 1.1076
 0.0000     1.10765 1.10794 1.10764 1.10779
 0.0104     1.10778 1.10808 1.10778 1.10794
 0.0208     1.10787 1.10834 1.10779 1.1079
```

Comment: ¿Nos pasas el código de tus intentos para poder probarlo?

Comment: Básicamente es es 
data['Hora']= float(data['Hora'].str[:2])/24 + float(data['Hora'].str[3:5])/600
y sus versiones separadas como :
Hora=int(data['Hora']

La data va mas o menos así:
22:00 1.10788 1.10803 1.10772
22:15 1.10777 1.10785 1.1075
22:30 1.1078 1.10788 1.10774
22:45 1.10781 1.10785 1.10742
23:00 1.10753 1.10769 1.10739
23:15 1.10756 1.10765 1.10742
23:30 1.1075 1.1076 1.10745
23:45 1.10756 1.10772 1.10741
00:00 1.10765 1.10794 1.10764
00:15 1.10778 1.10808 1.10778
00:30 1.10787 1.10834 1.10779
(4 columnas)

Comment: @AndresFelipeEstradaRodrigue edita tu pregunta y alli añade a informacion relevante

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Debido a varias problemáticas al usar Series o DataFrames decidí solucionar el problema de esta manera, construí una base de datos (HORAS) en la que se traduce lo que necesito para cada una de las 96 horas diferentes que se repiten en mis datos usando un documento CSV así:

```
Hora         M
22:00   0.916666667
22:15   0.927083333
22:30   0.9375
22:45   0.947916667
23:00   0.958333333
23:15   0.96875
23:30   0.979166667
23:45   0.989583333
...
```

con esto simplemente use un `pandas.merge`

```
import pandas as pd
data=pd.merge(data,Horas, on='Hora',how='outer')
```

y asi ahora mi base de datos se comporta de esta manera:

```
Hora    X1        X2      X3      M
22:00   1.10788 1.10803 1.10772 0.9167
22:15   1.10777 1.10785 1.1075  0.9271
22:30   1.1078  1.10788 1.10774 0.9375
22:45   1.10781 1.10785 1.10742 0.9479
23:00   1.10753 1.10769 1.10739 0.9583
23:15   1.10756 1.10765 1.10742 0.9688
23:30   1.1075  1.1076  1.10745 0.9792
23:45   1.10756 1.10772 1.10741 0.9896
00:00   1.10765 1.10794 1.10764 0
00:15   1.10778 1.10808 1.10778 0.0104
00:30   1.10787 1.10834 1.10779 0.0208
...
```